# How to populate two tables in create method [asp.net mvc]

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database

I have two tables in my database: `referents` and `users`.

```
Referents:
FirstName|LastName|Phone|Password|ConfirmPassword|UserName|Email
```

And

```
Users:
FirstName|LastName|UserRole|Password|ConfirmPassword|UserName
```

Currently `Create` method in my controler looks like:

```
// GET: Referents/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }
    // POST: Referents/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ReferentID,FirstName,LastName,Phone,Email,Password,ConfirmPassword")] Referents referents)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Referents.Add(referents);          
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(referents);
    }
```

Obvious, right now I'm populating only `Referents`.

**How to also populate `Users` table with certain data (UserName, LastName, UserName) in the same time?**

*In `UserRole` column I want to write string "referent".*

**EDIT** Added model:
Referents:

```
namespace StudentService.Models
{
    public class Referents
    {
        [Key]
        public int ReferentID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Морате унети име!")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Презиме је обавезно!")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Корисничко име је обавезно!")]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Унесите исправан број телефона.")]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Унесите исправну адресу електронске поште.")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Шифра је обавезна!")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Морате потврдити лозинку!")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: Is the UserName field Unique Key ? Are these two tables ( referents and users ) related in Database using foreign key ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the item for `users` and add it your your database.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ReferentID,FirstName,LastName,Phone,Email,Password,ConfirmPassword")] Referents referents)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Create the user data for the current referent.
        Users currentUser = new Users(){
            FirstName = referents.FirstName,
            UserRole = "referent"
            // .... Finish initializing fields of your model.
        };

        db.Referents.Add(referents); 
        // Save the new user in your database.         
        db.Users.Add(currentUser);

        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(referents);
}
```

Without seeing your model code it is hard to be specific, but you should be able to use that as an example. Just finish initializing the currentUser object to what you need it to be. It is possible this won't work depending on your schema.

Comment: I just added my model.

Comment: Ok -- You should be able to use the example code above and set this up.